# Frequency rank of Russian words

Tags: curated-data, linguistics

Mathematica contains the 31801 most frequent Russian words. These can be obtained using:

```
WordList["KnownWords", Language -> "Russian"]
```

Furthermore, the function `WordFrequencyData` returns the frequency of a word as a percentage:

[image: a sample output from WordFrequencyData]

How could I write a similar function `russianWordFrequencyRank` that returns **an integer corresponding to the word’s rank**?

For instance the most frequent word in the Russian language is "и" (which means "and"). My desired function should return 1 when fed this word.

```
russianWordFrequencyRank["и"] = 1
```

Here are some Russian words to use as examples:

```
russianWords = {"машина", "привет", "товарищ"}
```

Comment: Sadly since WordFrequencyData sends an individual request to a server for each word you give it, you will be rate-limited using that function. The easiest way is just to find the data elsewhere and use it offline, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, I may have been too hasty in my assumptions about "individual requests" but in general my point stands - WordFrequencyData uses Wolfram servers and has some caveats because of that.

Comment: Someone more well-versed in statistics might be able to give a sensible answer to the question of whether you could use the distribution of frequencies to estimate the rank - it looks like the frequencies of words is a LogNormalDistribution, so I wondered if you could use Probability to guess the rank of a word in some way. But I don't know what I'm talking about - it could be total nonsense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pursuant to my comments, here is a method to get all the frequencies by paginating requests to the WRI servers.

```
pages[l_, d_] := 
 Span @@@ NestList[{#[[2]], #[[2]] + d} &, {1, d}, Round[Length@l/d]]

words = WordList["KnownWords", Language -> "Russian"]

freqs = Join @@ 
   Table[WordFrequencyData[words[[p]], Language -> "Russian"], {p, 
     pages[words, 100]}];
```

This will get all the frequencies, 100 at a time (to prevent request timeouts). Sadly this takes approximately forever (which is why I suggest finding and downloading the source dataset for yourself, if you can).

I ran this for the first 1000 words in `words` with a page size of 100, which took about two minute, by doing

```
freqs = Join @@ 
   Table[WordFrequencyData[words[[p]], Language -> "Russian"], {p, 
     pages[words[[ ;; 1000]], 100]}];
```

Now your function is fairly simple: simply order the results by the frequency data and get the position of a word:

```
Position[Keys@ReverseSort@DeleteMissing@freqs, "была"][[1, 1]]
```

Of the first 1000 words, that is the 18th most common.

Or in function form:

```
russianWordFrequencyRank[w_] := 
 Position[Keys@ReverseSort@DeleteMissing@freqs, w][[1, 1]]

russianWordFrequencyRank["дан"]
```

which gives 357 - that is, it is the 357th most-common word in the Russian language that exists in the first 1000 words in `words`. If you create `freqs` based on all of `words`, you should get roughly the correct result.

Comment: Off topic a bit, but I am surprised that the word `"дан"` is so high in the rankings, or even at all made it in the 1000 most frequent words, given that it is a rather specialized term, used for the type of black belt one can have in certain martial arts like karate or taekwondo.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't know if `WordList["KnownWords", Language -> "Russian"]` is ordered any particular way, so it is just that it happened to be the most popular word in a selection of 1000 of the 31801 "known" words. I would imagine "dan" (means the same, I guess it's just a different transliteration) is just as likely to be the most popular in that kind of subset in if we did the same in English.

Answer (score 4):

Using Carl Lange's excellent idea of "paginating requests to prevent timeouts" and some psychological balm from `Monitor`, I downloaded all the data from Wolfram's server.

I then sorted it by rank and uploaded it github for future convenience.

```
data = Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccosnett/russianWordFrequenciesRanks/main/russianWordFrequencies.mx"]
```

[image]

```
russianWordFrequencyRank[w_] := Position[Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccosnett/russianWordFrequenciesRanks/main/russianWordFrequencies.mx"], {w, _, _}, 3][[1, 1]];
```

.

```
russianWordFrequencyRank["товарищ"]
```

> 1239